# Javascript Callback Functions defined in Iframe

Tags: javascript, jsf, iframe, callback

I'm trying to integrate Drools-Guvnor standalone editor in my spring-webflow-jsf-richfaces applicaton.
I'm displaying the guvnor-editor in an iframe (inside a richfaces-modalpanel).
As per documentation, guvnor exposes a javascript object along with callback functions for the parent application to communicate

```
    var guvnorEditorObject = {
    getDRL: function (callbackFunction),
    getBRL: function (callbackFunction),
    registerAfterSaveAndCloseButtonCallbackFunction: function (callbackFunction),
    registerAfterCancelButtonCallbackFunction: function (callbackFunction),
    getAssetsUUIDs: function()
}
```

Now my question is how do I register these callback functions inside my jsf page?
For example, I want to close the modal panel window if user clicks on close button.
A sample code would be really helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to resolve this issue by using javascript setTimeout function.

The root problem was that guvnorEditorObject was created dynamically and hence not available on immediate load of iframe.

Here is the code which is called on load of iframe.

```
        function register() {
        var guvnorEditorObject = window.document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.guvnorEditorObject;
        if(guvnorEditorObject){
            //guvnorEditorObject.getDRL(function(drl){alert('drl: '+drl);})
            //guvnorEditorObject.getBRL(function(brl){alert('brl: '+brl);})
            guvnorEditorObject.registerAfterSaveAndCloseButtonCallbackFunction(function(){guvnorEditorObject.getDRL(function(drl){alert('drl: '+drl);window.close();})});
            guvnorEditorObject.registerAfterCancelButtonCallbackFunction(function(){alert('Cancel button clicked');});              
            //alert(guvnorEditorObject.getAssetsUUIDs());       
        }else{
             setTimeout(register,250);
        }
    }
```